# Responsive dynamic images with fixed height

Tags: javascript, image, css, responsive-design

I'm implementing a design that has full-width images with a fixed height (or the height only changes at certain breakpoints). I want the image to always fill its container while maintaining its aspect ratio.

If I implement this as a background image, it's simple enough to add `background-size: cover`:

```
.cover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url(myimage.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7542mys/

If you try resizing the browser window, you'll see that the image covers the entire area by essentially scaling the image up.

The issue is that I want to change the image source depending on the resolution, so that I don't have to serve gigantic assets to mobile devices. If I knew the image URLs at build time, I could use media queries for that, however, these are dynamic images that I only know the URLs for at runtime.

At runtime, I can generate image URLs for cropped and resized images, so ideally I'd want to do something like:

```
<div class="cover">
  <img src="getImageUrl('image.jpg', 320, 500)" srcset="getImageUrl('image.jpg', 320, 500) 320w, getImageUrl('image.jpg', 640, 500) 640w, getImageUrl('image.jpg', 1000, 500) 1000w" sizes="100vw">
</div>
```

And then somehow get the image to fill the container just like the background image would. But if I give the image a `height` and `width` of `100%`, it's obviously just going to stretch. Giving the image a `min-width: 100%` will set it to be as wide as its parent, but the height will be smaller.

The only way I've been able to get it to work is using `object-fit: cover`, but that has pretty bad browser support, and the polyfills I've found haven't worked with `srcset`: http://jsfiddle.net/Lctosbru/

Essentially, I'd like to get the same effect as `background-size: cover` or `object-fit: cover`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use an inline style to change the background image? That way you'd still be able to use cover and the other properties. This is one of the few exceptions that I use inline styling for.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the way I'll have to go. I don't relish the idea of having to basically write media queries in JS, but it might be the only way.